# Saving form file field state in mobile html app

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, offline

I am working on simple mobile html app, where main part is form with submitting some reports. I need to make this app works offline. It is pretty simple. I can save all fields to localStorage etc, except the file field one.

Is there any way, how can i get content of file input, save the values and restore them?

Or is something like this possible to do with PhoneGap or similar system for building native html apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest browsers and mobile browsers support FileSystem API. It is a fairly simple code, once you use them.

Please refer to [html5rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), which I had personally used to learn the API.

If you wish to go via Phonegap route, It is almost similar on phonegap. Refer [PhoneGap file API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) for the same.